# How to handle quotes in Perl when calling system commands?

Tags: perl, system

I'm trying to make a very simple script to call the PDFXchange viewer from a .desktop file. But I'm not able to do this because the bash is seeing things that I'm not aware:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $winepath = `winepath -w -0 "$ARGV[0]"`;

my $cmd=join ' ',
    'wine',
    '\'C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe\'',
    "\'$winepath\'";

print $cmd . "\\n";

exec $cmd;
```

Output

```
$ exec_pdfxcv 'pdf with spaces.pdf' 
wine 'C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe' 'Z:\media\FILES\pdf with spaces.pdf'\nsh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

I'm very beginner at Perl, so I run out of ideas very quickly after tried a couple of times with different quotes configurations.

Comment: You set the bar quite high.  Getting all those quotes and escapes right isn't easy.  See whether [ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/~rosch/String-ShellQuote-1.03/ShellQuote.pm) or [Win32::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/~haarg/Win32-ShellQuote-0.002002/lib/Win32/ShellQuote.pm) can help.

Comment: Of course you don't seem to be doing anything that benefits from having a shell in the way.  Have you considered using the LIST form of exec?

Comment: Did you try `my @cmd = ('wine', q('C:\...'), $winepath); exec @cmd` ... ?

Comment: @zdim good point there, didn't knew that it can be done this way, thanks for this!!

Comment: it appears to work I'll test more at home!

Comment: Good -- I asked since I couldn't test this particular one. I posted it now with comments (seems to be of interest to @JohnDoe as well). Please let me know whether it needs more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally make it work after a hundred of tries.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $winepath = `winepath -w -0 "$ARGV[0]"`;

exec 'wine', q(C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe), "".$winepath."";
```

I hope help someone!

If there is anyone interested in the .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=PDF XChange Viwer
Comment=View multi-page documents
Exec=exec_pdfxcv %U
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupWMClass=PDFXCview.exe
Icon=evince
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Office;Viewer;
MimeType=application/pdf;application/x-bzpdf;application/x-gzpdf;application/x-xzpdf;application/x-ext-pdf;application/postscript;application/x-bzpostscript;application/x-gzpostscript;image/x-eps;image/x-bzeps;image/x-gzeps;application/x-ext-ps;application/x-ext-eps;application/x-dvi;application/x-bzdvi;application/x-gzdvi;application/x-ext-dvi;image/vnd.djvu;image/vnd.djvu+multipage;application/x-ext-djv;application/x-ext-djvu;image/tiff;application/x-cbr;application/x-cbz;application/x-cb7;application/x-cbt;application/x-ext-cbr;application/x-ext-cbz;application/vnd.comicbook+zip;application/x-ext-cb7;application/x-ext-cbt;application/oxps;application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument;
```

Comment: Are you sure it's working? My assumption is that `"".$winepath.""` will just colapse to `$winepath` since you are concatenating `""`(which is an empty string) with `$winepath` and then another empty string at the end `""`.

Comment: I mean, the result is the same as if you would have used `$winepath`

Comment: As strange as it is, it's not. Without this strange concatenation of empties strings the error: "sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string" appears. My guess is that the return of winepath has different unicodes quotes and it fix it.

Comment: See my answer for a clear way to concatenate (put a variable inside `''`).   You can also always just do `q(') . $winepath . q(')` (what I also had in the answer originally).  This really is "strange."

Comment: I have a feeling that there's another level of shell which is why you need the extra quotes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you dodged the bullet (of the common inscrutable mangle of quotes and escapes) here, since you don't need the shell for what is done and the rest doesn't need much either.

Then use the list-form of [exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html), which bypasses the shell altogether. This can be done with [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) as well but, alas, not with backticks.

```
my $winepath = `winepath -w -0 "$ARGV[0]"`;
chomp $winepath;

my @cmd = (
    'wine', 
    q('C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe'),
    "'$winepath'"
); 
exec @cmd;
```

Note the use of the [q() operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) as single quotes, freeing the symbol `'` for use inside.

We should remove the newline from `$winepath` (returned by `qx`) and need to protect spaces inside it by adding `'` around it.

Going through the shell only makes it harder; do it only when you *specifically* need the shell.

Once you *do* need the shell, however, be aware of [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/%7Erosch/String-ShellQuote-1.03/ShellQuote.pm) and [Win32::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ehaarg/Win32-ShellQuote-0.002002/lib/Win32/ShellQuote.pm).

Finally, work through [Quoting the Shell](https://www.perl.com/article/quoting-the-shell/) from *Perl.com*.  A required reading in my opinion.

Comment: it didn't work =| same thing! I bet that any program would not work that use spaces the one the wine does. With the last argument with a return from winepath.

Comment: @MaikoID Fixed.  (I didn't think of `$winepath` having spaces.) That's why I first asked in a comment -- since I cannot test this `wine` thing.

Comment: [Quoting the Shell](https://www.perl.com/article/quoting-the-shell/) from Perl.com

Comment: @briandfoy "_Quoting the Shell from Perl.com_"  -- Wonderful, thank you for the link. Added